# what does it mean we cannot inset a new property between the existing ones

Tags: javascript

***We can’t insert a new property “between” the existing ones. Objects are just not meant for such use.***
I was reading an article on the array and I found this line can anyone elaborate on this for me.

link for article => https://javascript.info/array

Comment: It means you should treat object properties as unordered.

Comment: The sentence before the one you quoted explains exactly the reason "It is not convenient to use an object here, because it provides no methods to manage the order of elements." An objects properties simply have no guaranteed order and there is no way to determine any such ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This means object is not properly ordered and when order is important, it is not the best idea to use object as it is not meant for such use. Object doesn't guarantee the order of the properties. So, as in array if you want to insert between two elements, it doesn't make any sense. We don't use object for arranging elements. We use them for storing key-value pairs. The order is not important in object as we access elements through keys.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that line means is that Objects aren't sorted, and you can't control the sort of it. Please see the example below:

```js
const obj = {
  test1: 'val1', 
  test3: 'val3'
}

obj['test2'] = 'val2'

console.log(obj) 

// OUTPUT: -> {test1: "val1", test3: "val3", test2: "val2"}
```

so you see it wont put 'test2' in between 'test3' and 'test1'